# Is there someone who can help for time displaying

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

i want to display time between the time a button display on the screen and the time the user click on the button, after that i want to display the difference between these 2 time onto next scene

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like that:

```
private float firstClickTime, secondClickTime;
private float timeDifference;

public void button1_Click(){
firstClickTime=Time.time;
}

public void button2_Click(){
secondClickTime=Time.time;
timeDifference=secondClickTime-firstClickTime; //This give you passed time in seconds
}
```

You can use timeDifference variable anywhere you want after that.